# Plot terrain deformation over geomap

Tags: matlab, plot, geoplot

I'm trying to plot the deformation of the terrain like in this image
[floor deformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVRL.png)

I've tried with geoplot but I only get the map and none of the data. The deformation is in matrix form. I'm fairly new to Matlab so I would appreciate any advice you can give me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is always better to include the image directly into the question, instead of using a hyperlink, which may eventually become obsolete. Also, without any sample data or MWE, it is hard for people to help you. Please provide more details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.